# Parsing data in reactJs is wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

FINAL EDIT:

This question got too far away from point of it. Will not continue it.

*=====

This is edited question since we made a lot of advancement and came to this problem. Old question is left below.

I fetch data from API and get result but when trying to change state hook it gets changed.

```
// state hook
var [listaClanarina, setListaClanarina] = useState(null)

// this is function for easier fetching so i do not need to populate all data.
// It returns pure response to callback
window.fetchAPI('/clanarina/list', 'GET',
    null,
    null,
    function(response) { // callback
        response.json().then((clanarine) => {
            Solution1(clanarine)
            setTimeout(function() {
                Solution2(clanarine)
            }, 5000) // need to set timeout, if not both results are wrong
        })
    })

function Solution1(clanarine) {
    console.log(clanarine)
    setListaClanarina(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clanarine)))

    // This one work normally
}

function Solution2(clanarine) {
    console.log(clanarine)
    setListaClanarina(clanarine)

    // This one prints array where all properties `USERNAME` are `true` or `false`
}
```

[image: output]

So why does this happen?

================== old question with all edits =====================

I have `express.js` API function which produce response like this:

```
// Copied from linux console/terminal
[
  RowDataPacket {
    KORISNIK: 'ddd',
    MESEC: 5,
    DATUM_PLACANJA: 2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    KORISNIK: 'finalKorisnik',
    MESEC: 5,
    DATUM_PLACANJA: 2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z
  }
]
```

When I try accessing that endpoint through `Postman`, I get this result (which is okay)

```
// Copied from linux console/terminal
[
    {
        "KORISNIK": "ddd",
        "MESEC": 5,
        "DATUM_PLACANJA": "2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "KORISNIK": "finalKorisnik",
        "MESEC": 5,
        "DATUM_PLACANJA": "2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

but when I try getting it from my reactjs application i get this response:

```
// Copied from google chrome console
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { KORISNIK: true, MESEC: 5, DATUM_PLACANJA: "2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z" }
​​
DATUM_PLACANJA: "2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"
​​
KORISNIK: true
​​
MESEC: 5
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
1: Object { KORISNIK: false, MESEC: 5, DATUM_PLACANJA: "2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z" }
​​
DATUM_PLACANJA: "2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"
​​
KORISNIK: false
​​
MESEC: 5
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []
KalendarClanarina.js:32
```

As you can see, field `KORISNIK` has `true` and `false` values for some reason.

My React Application is parsing all API data good (30+ endpoints) up until now. Only difference I have is I have never requested data with `date` property so I guess problem is there.

I am simply fetching it from endpoint using `fetch` function like this:

```
  fetch("http://localhost:3000" + endpoint, {
    method: "GET"
  })
  .then((response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  })
```

EDIT: (here is server side code that)

```
router.get('/list', function(req, res) {
    sql.query(`SELECT KORISNIK, MESEC, DATUM_PLACANJA FROM CLANARINA`, (err, resp) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.status(500).end()
        }
        
        console.log(resp)
        return res.json(resp)
    })
})
```

```
KORISNIK is Varchar(32)
MESEC is Int
DATUM_PLACANJA is DATE
```

EDIT 2:

I found out temporary solution but I have no idea why is it happening and need to find that out.

Code for fetching data is inside function which looks like this:

```
window.fetchAPI = function(endpoint, method, contentType, body, callback) {
  var auth = cookies.get("ARToken");

  fetch("http://localhost:3000" + endpoint, {
    method: method,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': contentType,
        'Authorization': 'bearer ' + auth 
    },
    body: body
  })
  .then((response) => {
    callback(response);
  })
}
```

When i do not need content type and body, I just set them to `null` and it works in all places.

Now I tried doing same fetch but directly in code side by side with this function and also passing `null` to see if that was the problem, and looks like it is not the problem since fetch does indeed work.

So take a look at results I am getting and help me find out why:

```
    function ucitajClanarine() {

        // Here i use my fetchAPI function like I
        // normally do and I get that faulty response
        window.fetchAPI('/clanarina/list', 'GET',
        null,
        null,
        function(response) {
            response.json().then((clanarine) => {
                console.log(clanarine) // faulty parse
                setListaClanarina(clanarine)
            })
        })

        // Here I imitate that function with all nulls
        // I would pass for content type (authorization is
        // not used for this scenario on server but I set it
        // just in case just like function would do)
        // and also i did not print it inside that .then()
        // but passed it to callback function like my 
        // fetchAPI function does only this time it gives
        // right result.
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/clanarina/list',
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': null,
                    'Authorization': 'bearer '
                },
                body: null
            }
        )
        .then((response) => {
            ddd(response) // good parse
        })
    }

    function ddd(response) {
        response.json().then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
```

Why does it make this problem when both are totally same?

Here is image of code for side by side comparison:

[image]

EDIT 3:
I found the problem. When I remove line `setListaClanarina(clanarine)` then console prints normal result and in state I still have `null`. When I add it back, console print wrong result and in state i have wrong array.

EDIT 4:
To Summarize this long question,

```
var [listaClanarina, setListaClanarina] = useState(null)

...

fetch('http://localhost:3000/clanarina/list',
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': null,
                    'Authorization': 'bearer '
                },
                body: null
            }
        )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((uujasyfhaso) => { // set random parameter name for test purposes
            console.log(uujasyfhaso)
            setListaClanarina(uujasyfhaso) // faulty line
        })
```

If I run code like this i get that wrong response with parameter `KORISNIK` being `true/false`

If i delete that faulty line `setListaClanarina(uujasyfhaso)` I get normal response from that `console.log` above

Here is one more image:
[image]

Comment: Hey! what does getting data with "date" property mean?

Comment: Just a guess. I can see that date is coming as a string. Is there any conversions apllied in API before returning to react?

Comment: @SarveshChitko Property of type `DATE`. Not `varchar`, not `int` etc, but `DATE`. I thought that might be helpful since I guess problem is in that

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran I did put it in edit. No there is not

Comment: Did u try to parse the response.data as plain text (```response.text()```) just to be sure that the json is as expected?

Comment: @Mischa I don't think that is the problem, since the postman response looks okay.

Comment: @Mischa `.text()` gives `[{"KORISNIK":"ddd","MESEC":5,"DATUM_PLACANJA":"2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"},{"KORISNIK":"finalKorisnik","MESEC":5,"DATUM_PLACANJA":"2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"}] KalendarClanarina.js:32
`

Comment: I found problem in one line and did summarize it at the end of question. Please take a look @SarveshChitko

Comment: Did edit again. Summarized it at top with cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

Does not make sense. If the data of the response in plain text is this:

```
[{"KORISNIK":"ddd","MESEC":5,"DATUM_PLACANJA":"2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"},{"KORISNIK":"finalKorisnik","MESEC":5,"DATUM_PLACANJA":"2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"}]
```

... then the `response.json()` is guaranteed to work fine:

```js
const input = `[{"KORISNIK":"ddd","MESEC":5,"DATUM_PLACANJA":"2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"},{"KORISNIK":"finalKorisnik","MESEC":5,"DATUM_PLACANJA":"2022-07-27T22:00:00.000Z"}]`;
const response = new Response(input);

response.json()
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Also i don't understand where your output comes from. As you can see the output here is correct.

Comment: It does not. I ran some tests and came with strange results (one working) and I am trying to find out why but have no idea. Edit coming in few minutes

Comment: I did found problem. Take a look at the end of original question